# WPF Combobox binding a list of countries in vb.net

Tags: wpf, xml, vb.net, data-binding, combobox

I have a WPF combobox

```
  <ComboBox x:Name="tCountry" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="96,151,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="146" TabIndex="6"/>
```

and some xml data I extracted from the unicode the (CLDRs)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<country>
    <territory type="AC">Ascension Island</territory>
    <territory type="AD">Andorra</territory>
    <territory type="AE">United Arab Emirates</territory>
    <territory type="AF">Afghanistan</territory>
    <territory type="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</territory>
    <territory type="AI">Anguilla</territory>
    <territory type="AL">Albania</territory>
    ....
</country>
```

How can I have it so the Combobox is populated with these countries so that I can extract the 2 letter iso code when they submit the data in vb.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `XmlDataProvider` to retrieve the fields from the XML file:

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="xml" Source="data.xml" />
```

Then bind it using `XPath` using the `SelectedValuePath` attribute:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource xml},XPath=/country/territory}" 
     SelectedValuePath="{Binding XPath=@type}" />
```

Now use `SelectedValue` to get the abbreviations (or use a binding for it).

```
private void combo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show((string)(sender as ComboBox).SelectedValue);
}
```